# Microsoft skydrive command line

Tags: windows-live, onedrive

Is there a command line tool for uploading to [Skydrive](http://skydrive.live.com) like [Google docs cmd tool](http://code.google.com/p/google-docs-upload/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has not made one themselves. Combined with the fact that they (still) haven't released an API is enough proof that there is no such tool since it would be pretty much impossible to make one without having an API for it.

You can read this, its self explanatory.
http://www.windowslivetaskforce.com/view/99

From this site: "However, the official API has not been publicised or documented by Microsoft. Presumably, therefore, it is not intended for public use, or at least not yet."

Meaning it's pretty much impossible for the public to make any application for skydrive. Microsoft hasn't made any either and clear thinking tells me that if Microsoft would make an application, it's probably going to be on with a GUI, rather than a CLI.

So all in all I guess you have to wait for the public API and wait for developers to create a tool like this, or make one yourself using the API

Answer (score 1):

It looks like MS have a Skydrive API now - [Python and command-line interface for Microsoft LiveConnect SkyDrive REST API v5.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-skydrive)

Comment: thanks, MS didn't give API access to SkyDrive cloud storage before